# Using C MPI syntax in a C++ application

Tags: c++, c, mpi

I am developing a C++ MPI application. I have some existing code that is a C MPI application which partly do what I want, so I should be able to copy some of the code (or rewrite it in a cleaner C++ way) into my new program. Since the C++ interface to MPI is being deprecated (and it is much harder to find documentation), I am seriously considering using the C interface to MPI in my C++ application. Is it a god idea to mix the C MPI interface with a C++ MPI application, or do I really need to learn to use Boost?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no harm in using a C API from a C++ application. Many popular APIs are written in C (the Windows API comes to mind as an example. Or POSIX. Or SQLite, zlib, Python or dozens and dozens of others).

So if that seems like the most convenient solution, go ahead and use the C API. It should be fairly easy to write some thin rappers to C++'ify it a bit yourself.

But apart from this, it is *always* a good idea for a C++ developer to learn and use Boost. Since Boost has a MPI library, it may, at the very least, be worth checking it out.

And in the end, go with what seems easiest to use for *you*, in your situation.

Comment: +1.  Most of the C++ programmers I know who use MPI use the C API (even before the C++ bindings were deprecated, as they were never all that great).  The MPI forum seems to have decided to focus on providing solid Fortran+C bindings and let third parties make the nice interfaces to other languages, which seems a reasonable choice.   Those C++ programmers I know who do use the Boost.MPI think they're great.

Comment: Just as a side note question...When one tries to utilize C and C++ syntaxs in the same code, How significant is the role of the compiler? Or is it?

Comment: @Ashmohan: What do you mean? The role of the compiler is *always* pretty significant when you compile code, isn't it?

Comment: @jalf: My question was related to the above context, "For example when C interface of MPI is being used in a C++ application". As Johnathan cited above that the MPI forum is focused on providing C bindings, I wanted to know of any particular compiler issues that may arise in cases where you have a C++ application with C interface to MPI

Comment: No, C++ is (mostly) source compatible with C. Any C++ programmer who's written more than 30 lines of code will have used a C API. You just include the header, link the library, call the functions.

Comment: I'm determined to at least try this approach, but so far it seems as if I'm effectively forced to write large of my program as normal C, even the non-MPI parts. Since C MPI doesn't know how to handle classes, it seems I must store the data I wish to transfer in structs and have everything as public variables.

Comment: That's generally true in C++. Only POD types can be treated as "raw chunks of memory". So anything you want to send across a network has to be a POD type (basically a C-style struct), regardless of API. One option *could* be to use a serialization library (Boost has a nice ony) to serialize your classes, but obviously that adds a certain amount of overhead

Comment: So I can write my C++ program using the C bindings for MPI, and then I should compile it with mpic++? Is that compiler going to be deleted as well?